# Adding significance brackets between bars with subgroups in bar plot ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, significance

I am trying to create a figure with brackets indicating significance between sublevels of my bar plot. The goal is to create something that looks like this based on results from a Wilcoxon test:

[image]

However, I can't seem to figure out how to include brackets that compare the sublevels (Active 1 Week Post to Sham 1 Week Post; Active 8 Weeks Post to Sham 8 Weeks Post).

Here is my data:

```
dat_ex <- dput(dat_ex)
structure(list(id = c("Participant 1", "Participant 1", "Participant 1", 
"Participant 1", "Participant 1", "Participant 1", "Participant 1", 
"Participant 1", "Participant 1", "Participant 1", "Participant 1", 
"Participant 1", "Participant 1", "Participant 1", "Participant 1", 
"Participant 1", "Participant 1", "Participant 1", "Participant 1", 
"Participant 1", "Participant 1", "Participant 1", "Participant 1", 
"Participant 1", "Participant 1", "Participant 1", "Participant 1", 
"Participant 1", "Participant 1", "Participant 1", "Participant 2", 
"Participant 2", "Participant 2", "Participant 2", "Participant 2", 
"Participant 2", "Participant 2", "Participant 2", "Participant 2", 
"Participant 2", "Participant 2", "Participant 2", "Participant 2", 
"Participant 2", "Participant 2", "Participant 2", "Participant 2", 
"Participant 2", "Participant 2", "Participant 2", "Participant 2", 
"Participant 2", "Participant 2", "Participant 2", "Participant 2", 
"Participant 2", "Participant 2", "Participant 2", "Participant 2", 
"Participant 2", "Participant 1", "Participant 1", "Participant 1", 
"Participant 1", "Participant 1", "Participant 1", "Participant 1", 
"Participant 1", "Participant 1", "Participant 1", "Participant 1", 
"Participant 1", "Participant 1", "Participant 1", "Participant 1", 
"Participant 1", "Participant 1", "Participant 1", "Participant 1", 
"Participant 1", "Participant 1", "Participant 1", "Participant 1", 
"Participant 1", "Participant 1", "Participant 1", "Participant 1", 
"Participant 1", "Participant 1", "Participant 1", "Participant 2", 
"Participant 2", "Participant 2", "Participant 2", "Participant 2", 
"Participant 2", "Participant 2", "Participant 2", "Participant 2", 
"Participant 2", "Participant 2", "Participant 2", "Participant 2", 
"Participant 2", "Participant 2", "Participant 2", "Participant 2", 
"Participant 2", "Participant 2", "Participant 2", "Participant 2", 
"Participant 2", "Participant 2", "Participant 2", "Participant 2", 
"Participant 2", "Participant 2", "Participant 2", "Participant 2", 
"Participant 2", "Participant 1", "Participant 1", "Participant 1", 
"Participant 1", "Participant 1", "Participant 1", "Participant 1", 
"Participant 1", "Participant 1", "Participant 1", "Participant 1", 
"Participant 1", "Participant 1", "Participant 1", "Participant 1", 
"Participant 1", "Participant 1", "Participant 1", "Participant 1", 
"Participant 1", "Participant 1", "Participant 1", "Participant 1", 
"Participant 1", "Participant 1", "Participant 1", "Participant 1", 
"Participant 1", "Participant 1", "Participant 1", "Participant 2", 
"Participant 2", "Participant 2", "Participant 2", "Participant 2", 
"Participant 2", "Participant 2", "Participant 2", "Participant 2", 
"Participant 2", "Participant 2", "Participant 2", "Participant 2", 
"Participant 2", "Participant 2", "Participant 2", "Participant 2", 
"Participant 2", "Participant 2", "Participant 2", "Participant 2", 
"Participant 2", "Participant 2", "Participant 2", "Participant 2", 
"Participant 2", "Participant 2", "Participant 2", "Participant 2", 
"Participant 2", "Participant 1", "Participant 1", "Participant 1", 
"Participant 1", "Participant 1", "Participant 1", "Participant 1", 
"Participant 1", "Participant 1", "Participant 1", "Participant 1", 
"Participant 1", "Participant 1", "Participant 1", "Participant 1", 
"Participant 1", "Participant 1", "Participant 1", "Participant 1", 
"Participant 1", "Participant 1", "Participant 1", "Participant 1", 
"Participant 1", "Participant 1", "Participant 1", "Participant 1", 
"Participant 1", "Participant 1", "Participant 1", "Participant 2", 
"Participant 2", "Participant 2", "Participant 2", "Participant 2", 
"Participant 2", "Participant 2", "Participant 2", "Participant 2", 
"Participant 2", "Participant 2", "Participant 2", "Participant 2", 
"Participant 2", "Participant 2", "Participant 2", "Participant 2", 
"Participant 2", "Participant 2", "Participant 2", "Participant 2", 
"Participant 2", "Participant 2", "Participant 2", "Participant 2", 
"Participant 2", "Participant 2", "Participant 2", "Participant 2", 
"Participant 2"), item_num = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 
6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 12, 13, 13, 14, 14, 
15, 15, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 
10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 12, 13, 13, 14, 14, 15, 15, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 
3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 12, 
13, 13, 14, 14, 15, 15, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 
7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 12, 13, 13, 14, 14, 15, 15, 
1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 
11, 11, 12, 12, 13, 13, 14, 14, 15, 15, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 
4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 12, 13, 
13, 14, 14, 15, 15, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 
8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 12, 13, 13, 14, 14, 15, 15, 1, 
1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 11, 
11, 12, 12, 13, 13, 14, 14, 15, 15), tdcs = c("active", "sham", 
"active", "sham", "active", "sham", "active", "sham", "active", 
"sham", "active", "sham", "active", "sham", "active", "sham", 
"active", "sham", "active", "sham", "active", "sham", "active", 
"sham", "active", "sham", "active", "sham", "active", "sham", 
"sham", "active", "sham", "active", "sham", "active", "sham", 
"active", "sham", "active", "sham", "active", "sham", "active", 
"sham", "active", "sham", "active", "sham", "active", "sham", 
"active", "sham", "active", "sham", "active", "sham", "active", 
"sham", "active", "active", "sham", "active", "sham", "active", 
"sham", "active", "sham", "active", "sham", "active", "sham", 
"active", "sham", "active", "sham", "active", "sham", "active", 
"sham", "active", "sham", "active", "sham", "active", "sham", 
"active", "sham", "active", "sham", "sham", "active", "sham", 
"active", "sham", "active", "sham", "active", "sham", "active", 
"sham", "active", "sham", "active", "sham", "active", "sham", 
"active", "sham", "active", "sham", "active", "sham", "active", 
"sham", "active", "sham", "active", "sham", "active", "active", 
"sham", "active", "sham", "active", "sham", "active", "sham", 
"active", "sham", "active", "sham", "active", "sham", "active", 
"sham", "active", "sham", "active", "sham", "active", "sham", 
"active", "sham", "active", "sham", "active", "sham", "active", 
"sham", "sham", "active", "sham", "active", "sham", "active", 
"sham", "active", "sham", "active", "sham", "active", "sham", 
"active", "sham", "active", "sham", "active", "sham", "active", 
"sham", "active", "sham", "active", "sham", "active", "sham", 
"active", "sham", "active", "active", "sham", "active", "sham", 
"active", "sham", "active", "sham", "active", "sham", "active", 
"sham", "active", "sham", "active", "sham", "active", "sham", 
"active", "sham", "active", "sham", "active", "sham", "active", 
"sham", "active", "sham", "active", "sham", "sham", "active", 
"sham", "active", "sham", "active", "sham", "active", "sham", 
"active", "sham", "active", "sham", "active", "sham", "active", 
"sham", "active", "sham", "active", "sham", "active", "sham", 
"active", "sham", "active", "sham", "active", "sham", "active"
), One_Week_Post = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1), time_point2 = c("Baseline", 
"Baseline", "Baseline", "Baseline", "Baseline", "Baseline", "Baseline", 
"Baseline", "Baseline", "Baseline", "Baseline", "Baseline", "Baseline", 
"Baseline", "Baseline", "Baseline", "Baseline", "Baseline", "Baseline", 
"Baseline", "Baseline", "Baseline", "Baseline", "Baseline", "Baseline", 
"Baseline", "Baseline", "Baseline", "Baseline", "Baseline", "Baseline", 
"Baseline", "Baseline", "Baseline", "Baseline", "Baseline", "Baseline", 
"Baseline", "Baseline", "Baseline", "Baseline", "Baseline", "Baseline", 
"Baseline", "Baseline", "Baseline", "Baseline", "Baseline", "Baseline", 
"Baseline", "Baseline", "Baseline", "Baseline", "Baseline", "Baseline", 
"Baseline", "Baseline", "Baseline", "Baseline", "Baseline", "Eight_Weeks_Post", 
"Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", 
"Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", 
"Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", 
"Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", 
"Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", 
"Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", 
"Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", 
"Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", 
"Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", 
"Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", 
"Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", 
"Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", 
"Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", 
"Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", 
"Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", "Baseline", 
"Baseline", "Baseline", "Baseline", "Baseline", "Baseline", "Baseline", 
"Baseline", "Baseline", "Baseline", "Baseline", "Baseline", "Baseline", 
"Baseline", "Baseline", "Baseline", "Baseline", "Baseline", "Baseline", 
"Baseline", "Baseline", "Baseline", "Baseline", "Baseline", "Baseline", 
"Baseline", "Baseline", "Baseline", "Baseline", "Baseline", "Baseline", 
"Baseline", "Baseline", "Baseline", "Baseline", "Baseline", "Baseline", 
"Baseline", "Baseline", "Baseline", "Baseline", "Baseline", "Baseline", 
"Baseline", "Baseline", "Baseline", "Baseline", "Baseline", "Baseline", 
"Baseline", "Baseline", "Baseline", "Baseline", "Baseline", "Baseline", 
"Baseline", "Baseline", "Baseline", "Baseline", "Baseline", "Eight_Weeks_Post", 
"Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", 
"Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", 
"Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", 
"Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", 
"Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", 
"Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", 
"Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", 
"Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", 
"Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", 
"Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", 
"Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", 
"Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", 
"Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", 
"Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", 
"Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post", "Eight_Weeks_Post"), 
    score = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), change = c("Bto1", 
    "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", 
    "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", 
    "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", 
    "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", 
    "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", 
    "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", 
    "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", 
    "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", 
    "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", 
    "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", 
    "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", 
    "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", 
    "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", 
    "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", 
    "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto1", "Bto8", 
    "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", 
    "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", 
    "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", 
    "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", 
    "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", 
    "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", 
    "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", 
    "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", 
    "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", 
    "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", 
    "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", 
    "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", 
    "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", 
    "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", 
    "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8", "Bto8"), 
    chgbroad = c(0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
    1, -1, -1, 0, -1, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
    -1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, -1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, -1, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, -1, -1, 0, -1, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 1, -1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 1, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 1, -1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 1, -1, 0, -1, 
    0, -1, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, -1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -240L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

And here is the code I have for the plot without brackets:

```
sum_dat_ex <-
  dat_ex %>%
  group_by(id,tdcs, change) %>%
  summarise(chgacc = mean(chgbroad), se = std.error(chgbroad), sd = sd(chgbroad)) %>%
  mutate(chgacc = if_else(chgacc == 0,-0.0017,chgacc)) %>%
  mutate(se = if_else(chgacc < 0, se*-1,se)) %>%
  mutate(ast_space = if_else(chgacc < 0, -0.02,0.02)) %>%
  mutate(signif_Bto1 = (if_else((id == 'Participant 2' & tdcs == 'active' & change == 'Bto1'), '1','0'))) %>%
  mutate(signif_Bto8 = (if_else((id == 'Participant 1' & tdcs == 'sham' & change == 'Bto8'),'1','0')))
sum_dat_ex


# Creating Barplot:

colorpicks <- c("blue", "red")

barplot <-ggplot(data=sum_dat_ex,
                           aes(x=tdcs, y=chgacc, fill = change)) +
  #scale_fill_manual("change",name = "Follow up Time Point", values = colorpicks)+
  geom_col(width = 0.7, position = position_dodge(0.7)) +
  facet_wrap(~id, dir = "h") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = colorpicks, labels = c('1 Week Post','8 Weeks Post'))+
  geom_text(data = sum_dat_ex[sum_dat_ex$signif_Bto1 == "1", ], 
            aes(y=chgacc + se + ast_space, label="*"), size=7, nudge_x = -0.175)+ #  y=chgacc + (-1*.02), nudge_x = 0.25
  geom_text(data = sum_dat_ex[sum_dat_ex$signif_Bto8 == "1", ],
            aes(y=chgacc + se + ast_space, label="*"), size=7, nudge_x = 0.175)+ #  y=chgacc + (-1*.02), nudge_x = 0.25
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c('Active','Sham'))+ # Only needed for graphs on the bottom
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::label_percent(accuracy = 1), limits = (c(-.35,.4))) +
  labs(y = "Change from Baseline", fill = 'Follow up Time Point')+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=chgacc-se,ymax=chgacc+se), width = 0, position = position_dodge(.7))
barplot
```

Here is what I have attempted to create brackets:

```
stat.test1 <- dat_ex %>% 
  dplyr::filter(change == 'Bto1') %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  wilcox_test(chgbroad ~ tdcs) %>%
  adjust_pvalue(method = "fdr") %>%
  add_significance("p.adj")
stat.test1 

stat.test1 <- stat.test1 %>% add_xy_position(x = 'tdcs')
barplot+ stat_pvalue_manual(stat.test1)


stat.test2 <- dat_ex %>% 
  dplyr::filter(change == 'Bto8') %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  wilcox_test(chgbroad ~ tdcs) %>%
  adjust_pvalue(method = "fdr") %>%
  add_significance("p.adj")
stat.test2


stat.test1 <- stat.test1 %>% add_xy_position(x = 'tdcs')
barplot + stat_pvalue_manual(stat.test1)
```

But the error I get is "Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'change' not found"

Is it possible to do this? Or do I need to create the brackets manually?